# Where would i find the code to edit an iframe ( youtube video) in shopify for a blog?

Tags: shopify

Where would I find the code to edit an iframe (youtube video) in Shopify? Right now in a blog it is not resizing in mobile and looks half cut off. I have looked in the article folder, blog folder, theme.liquid. I've checked everywhere. I don't even know what code to send you guys so you can help me figure it out. Basically what I am trying to do is find the code and then somehow resize it so it doesn't look cut off in mobile view. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: It's probably in one of the "snippets". You'll get a better solution on Shopify forums.

Comment: Thank you.. I figured it out. I actually did try in shopify forums and nobody knew.  It was in the blog pages and not the liquid files .. it was staring me right in the face the whole time haha. Once I found the code I came across this which helped make it responsive. So for anyone else that wants to know how to make iframe responsive .. here is the link to changing the code :) https://avexdesigns.com/blog/responsive-youtube-embed#:~:text=The%20fix%20was%20actually%20quite,%25%20height%2C%20with%20absolute%20position.